# add var in smarty for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, smarty, addition

I have a question about smarty "for" loop.

I try to add var value on each iteration like in a for loop in php like this:

```
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
{
   $foo += 5;
}

echo $foo // 25
```

But I need to do the same in smarty, I've tried to add values in a for loop of smarty like this:

```
{for $i=0 to {$sale_info[record].id_payment_type|@count}-1}             
   {if {$sale_info[record].id_payment_type[{$i}]} eq "1" }                                  
       {math equation="(x + x)" x={$sale_info[record].prices[{$i}]}}
   {/if}
{/for}
```

But I don't get result. Is possible to do something like x+=20 in smarty?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No it is not possible with builtin functions. Don't try and find a way to do it. All the data you need in the template should be generated before you send it to Smarty. So basically put that loop in the php code that builds the data and add the result to the data.

Comment: Ok man, I will do it. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you can do such things in Smarty. However there is no `for` loop in Smarty.

There is a simple example:

```
{assign var="y" value=0}
{section name=sec start=0  loop=5}
    {math equation="(x + x + y)" x =$smarty.section.sec.iteration y=$y assign="y"}
    {$y}<br />
{/section}
```

That makes calculation and assign it into `$y` variable.

Output for this will be:

```
2 // 1 + 1 + 0
6  // 2 + 2 + 2
12 // 3 + 3 + 6
20 // 4 + 4 + 12
30 // 5 + 5  + 20
```

However if possible and reasonable I still recommend you doing complex calculations in PHP and use Smarty only to display content.